# PySpark LSH approxSimilarityJoin taking too much time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, euclidean-distance, approximation

I want to find Jaccard Index for following dataset, so here's my approach:

```
df_1(89k records):

id     desc_array
1      [dde,jhb..]
3      [bjdhwb,hdjgvg,gd,...]
4      [bvcdhgs,hhj,...]
.
.

df_2(500 records):

id     desc_array
1      [dde,jhb..]
2      [bjdhwb,hdjgvg,gd,...]
5      [bvcdhgs,hhj,...]
.
.

model = Pipeline(stages=[
        HashingTF(inputCol = "desc_array", outputCol="vectors"),
        MinHashLSH(inputCol = "vectors", outputCol="lsh", numHashTables=1000)
    ]).fit(df_1)

db_hashed = model.transform(df_1)

model_final = Pipeline(stages=[
        HashingTF(inputCol = "desc_array", outputCol="vectors"),
        MinHashLSH(inputCol = "vectors", outputCol="lsh", numHashTables=1000)
    ]).fit(df_2)

db_hashed_final = model.transform(df_2)

db_matches = model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(db_hashed_final, db_hashed, 0.99, distCol="JaccardDistance")
db_matches.write.parquet(file_location)
```

Now this it's running for like 4 hours but still it's not finished, I believe it shouldn't take this much time cause dataframe is not that big(89k*500)

I have `250 executors` and these are my spark config:

```
spark_config = {}
spark_config["spark.executor.memory"] = "32G"
spark_config["spark.executor.memoryOverhead"] = "32G"
spark_config["spark.executor.cores"] = "32"
spark_config["spark.driver.memory"] = "2G"
```

Can someone please mention how can I optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to view the Spark UI and inspect the plan to identify bottlenecks, it seems likely the issue is the join. There are a few mechanisms for optimizing Spark performance when dealing with joins:

## Broadcast Joins

Depending on the size of each hashed dataframe, if one is much smaller than the other, you could do a broadcast join, where the smaller dataframe is copied to each executor and joined to each partition of the larger dataframe. For example, in the snippet provided, since `df_2` is much smaller than `df_1` (500 << 89k) and by extension `db_hashed_final` is much smaller than `db_hashed`:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import broadcast
model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(broadcast(db_hashed_final), db_hashed, 0.99, distCol="JaccardDistance")

# alternatively, if you're using Pyspark 3.x+
# model.stages[-1].approxSimilarityJoin(db_hashed_final.hint("broadcast"), db_hashed, 0.99, distCol="JaccardDistance")
```

## Partition Tuning

By default, when shuffling data for a join, Spark will split the data into 200 partitions, as configured by `spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` (seen [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-performance-tuning.html)). That number may need to be tuned for your dataset:

```
spark_config["spark.sql.shuffle.partitions"] = ...
```

While the number of partitions required may vary, some rules of thumb include setting it to 1-4x the number of cores (so in your case, 32-128) and/or making each partition about 100 MB, as detailed [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=daXEp4HmS-E).